# Error running python program from Teminal but it runs fine in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python2.7 in Pycharm and program runs fine when started from Pycharm

[image]

the output from Pycharm is

[image]

I am running the same program form terminal it shows error as shown below

[image]

---

After some discussions, I did the following

I changed the project interpreter in python to `which python2` path as shown below

[image]

Then running program from `Pycharm` works

[image]

but running it from terminal still have the same issue

[image]

Comment: What does `which python2` say?

Comment: type `which python2` to see if they are the same.

Comment: result from which python2 is /usr/local/bin/python2

Comment: So not the same python that pycharm is using...

Comment: in my opinion both are using 2.7, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Try changing the interpreter that pycharm is using to match the system python from `which`.  Then you can use pycharm to easily install the needed modules.

Comment: They are the same version but different installs, so different libraries are present.

Comment: can you please let me know which what should I do, like how to use result given by `which python2` command. sorry I am tyro in python 

Comment: The first image in your question shows the interpreter pycharm is using.  You can change to a new one there.  If you change to the same one shown by `which`, then if pycharm works, so will the command line.  Alternatively, you could use `#!` to allow the script to use the python that pycharm is currently using.  But bottom line is that command line and pycharm are using different installs of python.

Comment: Plese read my latest post, that Is not an answer

Comment: Does the project use a virtual environment? It will need to be activated before the script runs (and the shebang should then simply be `#!/usr/bin/env python` to defer the selection of the precise interpreter instance to the virtual environment). A common arrangement is to find an activation script with `ls */bin/activate` (it could be hidden; maybe try `ls .[!.]*/bin/activate` too?) though different arrangements are possible. If you find one, `source` it and try again. (There will be a command `deactivate` to exit; this command might not exist outside the virtualenv.)

Comment: I did `cd ~` then both `ls .[!.]*/bin/activate` and `ls */bin/activate` resulted in `ls: .[!.]*/bin/activate: No such file or directory`. Also I am usign standard shebang in all scripts.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it was not working is that I was trying to import the `XenAPI` which is located in some other location as shown below, which `pycharm` is able to access by using `import vkey.XenAPI` but from terminal its not.

[image]

Now this problem can be solved in 2 ways

1. By using `virtualenv` , follow [this tutorial](http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/virtualenv.html)
2. The good news is that we can directly install the `XenAPI` package using pip as shown below

[image]

Here is the screenshot which shows its working

[image]